# Is there a way to send browser console messages to a remote syslog (or other) server?

Tags: javascript, logging, console, syslog

I would like the console output of my web application to a centralized logging system. I am very flexible on the recipient side (syslog|whatever server).

There are plenty of packages to send messages to servers (and a quick solution would be to `fetch` to an ELK stack for instance).

This is not what I am looking for: I would like the **console errors/warnings** to be forwarded (and in addition the application-generated ones, but that part is easy).

Is there a consensual solution for this problem?

Comment: Which browser is that?

Comment: @LMC: this is for LuaKit (https://luakit.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

More of a POC than a solution perhaps but Remote Debuging Protocol can be used. With Firefox

1- **Start a debugging server**, the console of this instance will be captured. Pages to debug should be opened here. Dev tools must be opened.

```
kdesu -u lmc -c "firefox --start-debugger-server 9123"
```

2- **Start the debug Firefox client** by opening [about:debugging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/about:debugging) and connecting to the debug server. This instance might work a receiver for the packets only.

3- **Use `tshark` to capture packets**. Output can be sent to the logging facility.

```
tshark -i lo -f 'tcp port 9123' -Y 'data.data contains "pageError"' -T ek -e tcp.payload | jq -r '.layers.tcp_payload[0]' - | head -n2 | xxd -r -p
```

> Capturing on 'Loopback: lo'

**Output**
These json object might be sent to logging facility.

> 3 682:{"type":"pageError","pageError":{"errorMessage":"This page uses the non standard property “zoom”. Consider using calc() in the relevant property values, or using “transform” along with “transform-origin: 0 0”.","errorMessageName":"","sourceName":"https://www.acordesdcanciones.com/2020/12/la-abandone-y-no-sabia-chino-hidalgo.html","sourceId":null,"lineText":"","lineNumber":0,"columnNumber":0,"category":"Layout","innerWindowID":10737418988,"timeStamp":1629339439629,"warning":true,"error":false,"info":false,"private":false,"stacktrace":null,"notes":null,"chromeContext":false,"cssSelectors":"","isPromiseRejection":false},"from":"server1.conn1.child83/consoleActor2"}

Another `tshark` one-liner

```
tshark -i lo -f 'tcp port 9123' -Y 'data.data contains "pageError"' -T fields -e data.data | tail -n +6 | head -n3 | xxd -r -p >> data.json
```